# Used `tar -xz` without `f` and now program stuck

Tags: tar

Strangely, I had assumed the `-f` option was for "force", not for "file".

I ran `tar -xz` because I wanted to see if any files would be overwritten. Now it has extracted all the files but has not returned control back to me. Should I just kill the process? Is it waiting for input?

Comment: @ivan_posdeev's answer is correct for the two `tar`s on my system (BSD tar and  GNU tar), but if that's correct for your `tar`, then how did it extract the files?  You would have had to do something like `tar -xz < thetarfile.tgz`, but then it would have returned control at the end.  However, if you instead entered `tar -xz thetarfile.tgz`, then it should sit there waiting for you to put something onto standard input, and *not extract anything*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-f` commands [`tar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) to read the archive from a file. Without it, it tries to read it from `stdin`.

You can input `Ctrl-C` to kill it or `Ctrl-D` (`Ctrl-Z` in Windows) to send it `EOF` (at which point, it'll probably complain about incorrect archive format).

Comment: So it's expecting me to manually type in file names? I think it might be time to make `-f` default and not force us to type it anymore. What do you think?

Comment: By the way, `Ctrl-D` worked. It told me `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: Child returned status 1 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`. It seems like gzip is expecting actual archive binary data from stdin. I wonder how many people actually use it that way.

Comment: @ButtleButkus exactly, it's expecting raw archive data.

Comment: @ButtleButkus The intent is to be able to send the data (or read it from) anywhere - not necessarily a file - e.g. a database or other container or network link or tape or another program (e.g. a one doing compression that's not supported internally). It's not the common use case, but it is needed from time to time.

Comment: Something like this? `tar -xz;mysql -uroot -proot -e "select tarfile from database.table where id =42;"`

Comment: @ButtleButkus [not quite](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1641/raw-mysql-output-to-use-in-pipes): `mysql -N -s -r -e "select <whatever>"| tar -zx`.

Answer (score 1):

Without an `-f` option, tar will attempt to read from the TAPE device specified by the `TAPE` environment variable, or a file built into tar (usually something like `/dev/st0` or stdin) if `TAPE` isn't set to anything.

Comment: Any backing? http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar doesn't mention anything like "TAPE".

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Just going by the [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/tar.1.html) [pages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tar(1))

Comment: Excavations at the [git repo](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git) show that the relevant code is there since at least 1997 (`v1.12`, `5e0e89eac1a00a2edb87ea7b69f1f38c2b1249e1`), but till 2014 (`v1.28`, `f5048215892c1bf6cf602c41146c556f60a63a51`), `tar --help` output was apparently used as a source for the man page which didn't mention this behaviour.